# Simplest annotated line chart

Tags: google-visualization

this was [originally asked on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/wHKosV3lNHs/jbeLFHq_Ed4J) but since I received no replies, I'm asking here on SO.

I am plotting basic data like temperature, various counts and such with date time and I like to append a third column as a further description.

E.g.

```
time, value, description
time, value, description
time, value, description
```

So I am looking at the simplest way of plotting that, as full screen as possible, as minimally (least LOC) as possible.

So far with https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/q1mczqc1/2/ I have not figured how to show the description (is it a infobox/selection? not sure on terminology), which in my example is the kernel version, when I click a point.

Furthermore I don't understand why on the right of the graph there are these null value labels:
http://s.natalian.org/2015-06-16/1434449447_1054x1058.png

And any tips to make http://s.natalian.org/2015-06-16/foo.html scale to fill the whole screen? I especially want to make it usable on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have not figured how to show the description (is it a infobox/selection? not sure on terminology)

In web development, this is called a tooltip. In Google charts, you can add a tooltip by replacing the commented line with the following one :

```
//data.addColumn('string', 'kernel');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```

So, the 3rd column will not be handled as a data series, but as a tooltip.

> Furthermore I don't understand why on the right of the graph there are these null value labels

The null values are shown, because (as previously stated), you have inserted 2 series of data ('Date' and 'kernel'). If you make the replacement mentioned before, the null values will be replaced

> And any tips to make .. scale to fill the whole screen ?

You can add the following option to configure the dimensions of the chart :

```
var options = {
    chartArea: {width: '80%', height: '80%'}
};
```

Furthermore, since the version of line charts you are using are slightly obsolete, you shoud replace

```
var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
```

with

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
```

---

**In the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1mczqc1/3/), you can find a final working version**

(with some more fixes, like horizontal axis range and legend positioning).

Comment: I need the date & number value to show too in the tooltip, formatted one on each line with the third row being tooltip string. How do I do that? focusTarget: 'category' doesn't show the number value (2nd column). https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/odo79nsz/1/

Comment: Google charts do not give you the capability to format the tooltip element. Thus, you will either have to create a column, where the description is concatenated with date & number, so that they are all shown in the same line. Or otherwise, you will have to edit the DOM manually with vanilla Javascript (which is quite "dangerous").

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you want to add third column as a description for each point.

If you add 3rd column like this

```
data.addColumn('string', 'kernel');
```

Google chart takes this as another series and because the data are string it can't draw the series and shows null.

You can add 3rd column as a tooltip.

```
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```

But for tooltip to work you need to change the line chart to visualization line chart

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
```

To make chart fill the screen you can change the div style.

```
<div id="linechart_material" style="height:100%;"></div>
```