# How to chart a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, highcharts, visualization

This follows on from [Simplest annotated line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284796/simplest-annotated-line-chart)

Where I have data like:

```
date       num   annotation
1435212223 48000 4.0.5-1-ARCH
1435622405 43000 4.0.6-1-ARCH
1435896936 48000 4.0.7-2-ARCH
```

It's actually coming from a simple script like `echo $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) $(uname -r) | log2csv`.

Now I want to graph the CSV. To do that in simple in shell for Google visualisation, it's something like:

```
cat <<END
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'temperature');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
END
cat $(ls -t *.csv) | while read time number annotation
do
       printf "data.addRow([new Date(%d), %d, \"%s\"]);\n" "${time}000" "$number" "$annotation"
done
```

As you can see, I simply append values to CSV, run a shell script and then that gets graphed with Google charts like so: https://jsfiddle.net/q1mczqc1/3/

However I am trying not to use Google, since my visualisations need to work offline. However when researching other charting libraries such as:

- http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart
- https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#line-chart-with-tooltips
- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

They seem to require the data in a JSON format (often complex, often mixing presentation and data), which is *non-trivial* to convert from CSV. The values typically seem to marked up to go from **column to row based**? (not sure on terminology)

So the elegant solution I'm looking for, is some row to graphing solution that doesn't require Google visualisation and has the least amount of code possible.

End result is me pressing return on `echo $RANDOM | log2csv --build-webpage` and refreshing my browser to see the new value.

What are good options or techniques here?

Comment: gnuplot? or do you want it to be js?

Comment: highchart has some csv reading mode, not sure how good it is though: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/csv/

Comment: did you ever solve this?